# how to order Arrays value as circular format in java?

Tags: java, arrays

i have array values as like

`String[] value = {"1","2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};`

suppose if i pass value "5" to tat array, it should be ordered as like

```
{"5","6","7","8","9","10",1","2","3","4"};...
```

how to do?plz anyone help?
thank u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is called rotation. You can use `Collections.rotate()` method. Convert the array to a list and pass it to the method. This will rotate the array in place since the list is backed by the array:

```
String[] value = {"1","2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(value), 5);
```

The above code will rotate the array  by a distance of 5. The resulting `value` array:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question has two interpretations:

- Rotate 5 steps, or
- rotate the array so that 5 is the first element (regardless of where it is in the array).

Here is a solution for both alternatives:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static String[] rotateArray(String[] arr, int n) {
        String[] rotated = new String[arr.length];
        System.arraycopy(arr, n-1, rotated, 0, arr.length-n+1);
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, rotated, arr.length-n+1, n-1);
        return rotated;
    }

    public static String[] rotateArrayTo(String[] arr, String head) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i].equals(head))
                return rotateArray(arr, i + 1);

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find " + head);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] value = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};

        // Rotate so that it starts at 5:th element
        value = rotateArray(value, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));

        // Rotate so that it starts with element "7"
        value = rotateArrayTo(value, "7");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

([ideone.com link](http://ideone.com/o9xTT/))

Answer (score 0):

first find the index of the entered value from the array..
and then in a loop move from the index to the final position.. and store these values in a new array.
after that, in the same result array, store the values from index 0 to the index of the entered value - 1.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to store the values in a different array. Just find the index [say `idx`] of the value passed. And then start a loop from the start of the array and swap the values starting from `idx`.
For example -

```
idx = [some-value]
while [idx < arr.length]
   temp = arr[i]
   arr[i] = arr[idx]
   arr[idx] = t
   idx += 1
   i += 1
```

**Update**:
I stand corrected by @aioobe. I simply worked out something for the 5th index - my bad. Here's something that works, if in case, you want to stay away from library functions -

```
private void slideLeft(String[] arr)
{
    String t = arr[arr.length - 1];
    String temp = null;
    int next = -1;

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        next = ( i == 0 ) ? arr.length - 1 : i - 1;
        temp = arr[next];
        arr[next] = t;
        t = temp;
    }
}
```

you'll need to call this method the number of times you need to shift the array members.

note: O(n^2) alert. not suitable for large shifts/arrays.