# Order an ArrayList<DayOfWeek> based on a specific value

Tags: java, arraylist, rotation, java-time, dayofweek

I have an `ArrayList<DayOfWeek>` let's say `["MONDAY","WEDNESDAY","FRIDAY"]`

My aim is to order it based on a `DayOfTheWeek` in a circular way.

Input: `"WEDNESDAY"`

SortedList: `["WEDNESDAY","FRIDAY","MONDAY"]`

The list is guaranteed to be sorted from Monday through Sunday. The input day is not guaranteed to be in the list, in this case the sorting starts from the next value present in the list.

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be sorted from Monday through Sunday from the outset? Is the input day of week guaranteed to be in the list?

Comment: The list is guaranteed to be sorted from Monday through Sunday. The input day is not guaranteed to be in the list, in this case the sorting starts from the next value present in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a method similar to this:

[how to order Arrays value as circular format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001137/how-to-order-arrays-value-as-circular-format-in-java)

Where each `DayOfWeek` has its own ID number corresponding to its intended position in ordering, so you can rotate around those numbers.

Answer (score 6):

### [`Collections#rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DayOfWeek> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY,
                DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

        Collections.rotate(list, list.size() - list.indexOf(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY));

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY]
```

**Interactive:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DayOfWeek> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY,
                DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the day: ");
        String day = scanner.nextLine();

        try {
            Collections.rotate(list, list.size() - list.indexOf(DayOfWeek.valueOf(day.toUpperCase())));
            System.out.println(list);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the day: wednesday
[WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already given the right idea: use `Collections.rotate()`. This is just to take the information from the comment into account:

> The list is guaranteed to be sorted from Monday through Sunday. The
> input day is not guaranteed to be in the list, in this case the
> sorting starts from the next value present in the list.

```
    ArrayList<DayOfWeek> list  = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    DayOfWeek input = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;
    
    int indexOfDesiredFirstDay = Collections.binarySearch(list, input);
    if (indexOfDesiredFirstDay < 0) {
        indexOfDesiredFirstDay = -indexOfDesiredFirstDay - 1;
    }
    Collections.rotate(list, -indexOfDesiredFirstDay);
    
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output in this example:

> [WEDNESDAY, FRIDAY, MONDAY]

Since the list will never be longer than 7 elements, we don’t need the efficiency of binary search, but `Collections.binarySearch()` is still a convenient method for finding the index of the element that we want to come first after rotation. `rotate()` accepts a negative amount of rotation, so we just negate (reverse the sign of) the index and pass it to that method. The calculated index may be beyond the end of the list, but `rotate()` can handle that too, so it’s OK.

Answer (score 0):

As the input day may be missing in the input list, a full list of weekdays is needed to be sorted with `Collections.rotate` and then filtered by the input list:

```java
public static List<DayOfWeek> orderWithDayFirst(DayOfWeek first, List<DayOfWeek> dows) {
    List<DayOfWeek> fullWeek = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.values());
    Collections.rotate(fullWeek, -first.ordinal());
    return fullWeek.stream().filter(dows::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Tests:

```java
// Sunday is available
System.out.println(orderWithDayFirst(
        DayOfWeek.SUNDAY,
        Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)));

System.out.println("====");

// No Friday
System.out.println(orderWithDayFirst(
        DayOfWeek.FRIDAY,
        Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)));
```

Output

```
[SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, SATURDAY]
====
[SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY]
```